# android - to set or not to set instance variables to null?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, ondestroy

I read an article the following Web site

[ http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html  ]

In the section, "destory the activity"

"Most apps don't need to implement this method because local class references are destroyed with the activity and your activity should perform most cleanup during onPause() and onStop(). However, if your activity includes background threads that you created during onCreate() or other long-running resources that could potentially leak memory if not properly closed, you should kill them during onDestroy()."

1. Do I need to initialize the instance to null during onDestroy()?
2. What does this mean "long-running resources" ? For example, you mean the imageview?
3. Do I need to initialize the Global Variable to null  during onDestroy()?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Does this instance is null during onDestroy()?
```

The instance of an object which has a non-static method being executed cannot be null. That is, the `Activity` instance (referenced by `this`) will not be null. Fields of that instance of the `Activity`, may be null depending on whether or not they were ever assigned, or unassigned.

```
2. What does this mean "long-running resources" ? For example, you mean the imageview?
```

'Long-running resources' refers to things which could live past the life-time of the `Activity`. This includes any `Thread` or `AsyncTask` which are executed asynchronously and may run past the existence of the `Activity`.

It could also mean when you pass the `Activity` (or something that keeps a reference to the `Activity` - like a non static inner class) to an external object which isn't tied to the life-cycle of the `Activity`. For example, if you post a `Runnable` to a `Handler` with a long delay, if that `Runnable` has a reference back to the `Activity` (like an anonymous instance), you should ensure that `Runnable` is removed from the `Handler` in onDestroy (or possibly before).

```
3. Do I need to null the global during onDestroy()?
```

I'm not sure what you're asking here. But if you're assigning a 'global' or static field to reference the `Activity`, that is generally a bad idea, so yes, assign it to null (or remove it altogether). Otherwise you'll be leaking the `Activity` with that reference (GC won't be able to release the memory).